# Is it possible to return code 1 if any Rspec errors present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I know about flag `--failure-exit-code` but it works only for `failures`. For example, I have this situation:

```
Finished in 0.35799 seconds (files took 16.03 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 2 errors occurred outside of examples
```

So, I have 0 failures due to 2 errors in my external lib. And in this case I want to have exit code 1 also. I am using `3.9.2` rspec version.

Comment: If it's possible you can bump rspec to 3.10 version and try this flag `--error-exit-code`. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/commit/0709dcb4c535940501b2fd3eec3880431a34c74f

Comment: awesome, will try!